# Change ViewModel property using button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm learning WPF and MVVM and I'm enjoying using it so far. I'm going for a purist style with no code-behind.

My software is simple: I have a bunch of POCO objects representing Contacts. The view has a listbox of all contacts on the left. By selecting a contact in the listbox, you see the details on the right, such as name. This works perfectly, the listbox is bound to a viewmodel which has a list of contacts, and the viewmodel also has a property called CurrentContact which the fields in the details view are bound to. (SelectedItem of Listbox is bound to the CurrentContect property, so it changes automatically as you select contacts in the list).

Here's the problem: I want a nice way of adding new contacts, preferably by setting "CurrentContact" to null, which leads to empty fields in the details, which I can then fill in and press save. My first choice was to add a "new" item at the bottom of the listbox, but this turned out to be hard to do since the listbox is bound to the viewmodel which does not have such a null object in the list. Instead, I added a button at the bottom of the list which sets CurrentContact to null. I need this button to change a property on my viewmodel, but I can't think of a way to use binding here. I have implemented a Command in my viewmodel which sets the property to null. This works, but seems like a ridiculous way of solving it, that's a ton of boilerplate code for something so simple. Is it really the only clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're pretty much doing it right. The boilerplate code is supposed to be there.

You want to use ICommand to add the populated object to your list.

```
public void InitializeCommands(){
    AddEContactCommand = new ICommandImpl(AddElement); //you'll have to derive an implementation for ICommand for this
}

public ICommand AddContactCommand
{
    get { return _addContactCommand; }
    set { SetValue(ref _addContactCommand, value); } //setvalue is wrapper for notifychanged from viewmodelbase abstract class
}
public void AddContact() {
     //do add contact
     //set properties null
}
```

Comment: That I need to implement ICommand to do real pure MVVM eventually is something I've accepted, the actual Save functionality for example. However, I can't imagine there isn't a nicer way when all I want to do is have one property of the ViewModel change. I mean, the same property is already changed by the Listbox using binding, so why can't I do something similar using a button?

Comment: The purpose of MVVM isn't to make things elegant, it's to separate the presentation layer from the logic that interacts with it. In this case you're trying to force the viewmodel logic into the view, and MVVM is trying (and succeeding) in frustrating your attempt :).

Comment: I disagree. Of course it's up to the ViewModel to take care of saving a new contact, but it's necessarily up to the View to handle interaction from the user. I'm not trying to force ViewModel logic into the view, I'm trying to communicate interaction from the user to the ViewModel.

Comment: When you say "I need this button to change a property on my viewmodel, but I can't think of a way to use binding here." If you could CHANGE YOUR VIEW MODEL with a binding ON THE VIEW, you would be doing logic in your view, which is exactly what MVVM does not want you to do. Instead the view connects to a command on the viewmodel, and the command on the viewmodel changes the property.

Comment: Then why doesn't MVVM have any problem with ListBox SelectedItem being bound to the CurrentContact property on my ViewModel? It's the exact same kind of interaction. The listbox lists all the Contacts in an ObservableCollection, when you select one of them, the CurrentContact of the ViewModel is immediately changed by the binding. Basically what I want is nothing more advanced than clearing the selection in the listbox (without using codebehind).

Comment: Alright, different tack: How is any of your bindings ever going to update your model in the DB unless you use codebehind to perform CRUD operations?

Comment: Well, for that I can only assume implementing ICommands in the viewmodel is the only option. Like I said, I expected to have to use this RelayCommand pattern eventually for Save functionality. I guess the problem here is that I feel I'm forced to use advanced communication between the view and the viewmodel in a situation where it should be simple. The fact that I'm using the same interface for editing and adding should be a pure view concern, I'm annoyed that I have to communicate it to the viewmodel.